# e value script program

Tags: python

So I am trying to get the e_values from the file

Comment: What does the file look like?

Comment: Ah. "the file". I know it well... There so many "the files" on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
e_value  = float(linearr[6])
```

With this:

```
e_value  = float(linearr[6])

if e_value > 1.0e-10:
  continue
```

That way, if `e_value` is greater than your threshold, the loop skips the current value and moves on to the next one.